# Getting All Entries from a Multi-User Google Calendar

Tags: python, google-api, google-calendar-api, gdata

So I have an enterprise calendar that it is the default Google calendar of one of the managers at an organization. She has her own entries on the calendar, but there are also many entries that appear to have originally been inputted on other users' calendars and shared with or copied to this default calendar. I'm trying to use the Python Google Calendars API to get a list of all of the events on the calendar. Unfortunately, it's only listing the events that have been added by the manager, even though the manager can see all of the other events. Here is my code for retrieving the entries within a specific date range:

```
def dateRangeQuery(calendar_service, startDate, endDate):
    query = gdata.calendar.service.CalendarEventQuery('default', 'private', 'full')
    query.start_min = startDate
    query.start_max = endDate
    feed = calendar_service.CalendarQuery(query)
    for entry in feed.entry:
        print entry.title.text
```

Is there any way to retrieve the other users' entries without having their login information?

Sorry I'm not that familiar with Google Calendars itself. On further investigation, I'm pretty sure what's happening is that other users are keeping calendars and sharing certain events with the managers. So my question boils down to this: is there a way to list shared events using the Google Calendars API?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be using the new Google Calendar API v3 and the [Google API Python Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/). No use developing against an old, deprecated version of the API.

It sounds like the Calendar with all the entries on it is a resource Calendar. If that's the case, you should authenticate as a user that has ownership rights to the resource calendar but you should retrieve entries for the resource calendar, not the user's primary calendar:

```
events = service.events().list(calendarId='resource@email-address.com').execute()

while True:
  for event in events.get('items', []):
    print event['summary']
  page_token = events.get('nextPageToken')
  if page_token:
    events = service.events().list(calendarId='resource@email-address.com', pageToken=page_token).execute()
  else:
    break
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for the heads up on the deprecated version. However, I don't think what I'm working with is a resource calendar. It is the manager's default calendar. She gives some staff members under her access to the calendar, and they can share events with her default calendar. Those are the events I want to access.

Comment: If it's actually on her calendar, not some other calendar that's shared with her, then it will show with the list() API call.

Comment: Well, it appears on her calendar, but she has the option to copy the entry to her calendar, so maybe the users have simply shared certain entries that appear on her calendar (her entries are solid; the entries from their calendars are translucent with diagonal lines in the background). Is there any way to get the API to list those entries other than copying them to her calendar? If copying is the only way, is there an easy way to automate the copying process?

Comment: copied calendar entries are not linked in any way after the copy (except for the fact that they have some data in common). Instead of copying the entries, the users should be inviting additional attendees to the event. This keeps a single calendar event in place instead of resulting in copies that must be managed individually.